# prove: $\mathbb{Q}(\omega\sqrt[3]{2}) \cong \mathbb{Q}(\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{\omega})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field

Let $\omega$ be a root of the polynomial: $f(x)=x^2+x+1\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Prove:
$\mathbb{Q}(\omega\sqrt[3]{2})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{\omega})$

my attempt:

I'd like to prove that there exists $\phi:\mathbb{Q}(\omega\sqrt[3]{2}) \to \mathbb{Q}(\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{\omega})$.

I'm wondering if it's enough (or even true), that since: $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)=\{a+ib\sqrt{3}|a,b\in \mathbb{Q}\}$,

then
$\mathbb{Q}(\omega)= \mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{3})$
it's enough to define $\phi$ as: $\phi(i\sqrt{3}\sqrt[3]{2})= \frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{i\sqrt{3}}$.

what am i missing in order to determine that $\phi$ is an isomorphism?

is this true that that both fields mentioned above equals? this will complete the proof, but I don't think it's true and also not sure how to prove that:$\mathbb{Q}(\omega\sqrt[3]{2}) \neq \mathbb{Q}(\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{\omega})$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The slightly easier way is to see that they are both solutions of the irreducible polynomial $x^3 -2$ so that

$$ \mathbb{Q} (\omega \sqrt[3]{2}) \cong \mathbb{Q} (\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{\omega} ) \cong \mathbb{Q}[x] / (x^3 -2)$$

From that construction you can easily see that the isomorphism is $\omega \sqrt[3]{2} \mapsto \frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{\omega}$

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Sofia is excellent. I will like to add on your last query about how to show that they are only isomorphic but not equal.

If possible let $$\mathbb{Q}(\omega\sqrt[3]{2}) = \mathbb{Q}(\frac{1}{\omega}\sqrt[3]{2})$$

But notice that $\frac{1}{\omega}=\bar{\omega}$ .

So $$\omega\sqrt[3]{2}+\bar{\omega}\sqrt[3]{2}=(\sqrt[3]{2})\cdot2\text{Re}(\omega)=-\sqrt[3]{2}\in \mathbb{Q}(\omega\sqrt[3]{2}) $$.

So $\mathbb{Q}(\omega\sqrt[3]{2})=\mathbb{Q}(\omega\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{2})$

And hence $\omega \in \mathbb{Q}(\omega\sqrt[3]{2})$ (As $\omega=\frac{\omega\sqrt[3]{2}}{\sqrt[3]{2}})$.

So $\mathbb{Q}(\omega\sqrt[3]{2})=\mathbb{Q}(\omega,\sqrt[3]{2})$ .

But you have $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega):\mathbb{Q}]=2$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=3$ and hence they are relatively prime . So the degree of their compositum ($=\mathbb{Q}(\omega,\sqrt[3]{2})$) is the product of $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega):\mathbb{Q}]$ and  $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}):\mathbb{Q}]$ .

(The same argument proves that the splitting field of $x^{p}-2$ is $\mathbb{Q(\sqrt[p]{2},\zeta_{p}})$ of degree $p(p-1)$, where $p$ is a prime and $\zeta_{p}$ is a primitive $p-th$ root of unity.

So

$[\mathbb{Q}(\omega,\sqrt[3]{2})):\mathbb{Q}]=6$.

But $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega\sqrt[3]{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=3$.

A contradiction.

Hence $$\mathbb{Q}(\omega\sqrt[3]{2}) \neq \mathbb{Q}(\frac{1}{\omega}\sqrt[3]{2})$$

I know this seems long but once you get used to splitting fields these degree arguments are much shorter.

Alternatively you have to use the explicit basis $\{1,\omega\sqrt[3]{2},(\omega\sqrt[3]{2})^{2}\}$ and show that $\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{\omega}$ does not lie in $\text{span}(\{1,\omega\sqrt[3]{2},(\omega\sqrt[3]{2})^{2}\})$ which is easier said than done.

Comment: What you're saying here is not true, as both extension field are isomporhic, they must have the same dimension over $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: As I said in the beginning of my answer that this is supposed to address your query about how to show that these two fields are just isomorphic but not equal. The crux of the argument lies in the fact that if both $\omega\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\frac{1}{\omega}\sqrt[3]{2}$ lie in the same extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ then it becomes the splitting field.

Comment: @Jneven Please re-read your comment. Your comment itself disproves the claim that $\Bbb{Q}(\omega\sqrt[3]{2})=\Bbb{Q}(\frac{1}{\omega}\sqrt[3]{2})$ which is what you asked in your last line that you "dont know how to prove that these extensions are not equal" . And that is what I showed in the answer that we are getting different degrees leading to a contradiction. However as Sofia's answer indicates these two are indeed isomorphic as given any irreducible polynomial $f(x)$ over $F[x]$ and roots $\alpha,\beta$ of $f(x)$, you have $F(\alpha)\cong F(\beta)$.